# Как вернуть хранимой процедурой результат в виде таблицы?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Перепробовал много вариантов, возвращает или пустую таблицу или вообще ничего. Вот последний вариант:

```
DECLARE @TabResult TABLE ([Name] TEXT,[NumberRequests] INT,[Date] DATE)

INSERT @TabResult EXEC [dbo].[GetTopFrequentlyRequested]
        @NumberRowsSelect = 10,
        @NamePeriod = N'Day'

SELECT  * FROM @TabResult
```

Вот часть процедуры

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTopFrequentlyRequested] @ScoringLines INT, @NamePeriod Char(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TabResult TABLE ([Name] TEXT,[NumberRequests] INT,[Date] DATE)
    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = GETDATE(), @OldDate DATE
    IF @NamePeriod = 'Day' AND @ScoringLines > 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT [ID] FROM [FrequentlyRequested] WHERE [ID] = 0) 
        BEGIN
            SET @OldDate = DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())
            INSERT INTO @TabResult ([Name],[NumberRequests],[Date]) SELECT TOP (@ScoringLines) [Name],[NumberRequestsDay],[DateDay] FROM [FrequentlyRequested] WHERE [DateDay] BETWEEN @OldDate AND @CurrentDate AND [NumberRequestsDay] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [NumberRequestsDay] DESC
        END
    ELSE IF (@NamePeriod IS NULL) OR (@ScoringLines IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            RAISERROR('Некорректные параметры запроса', 16, 10);
            RETURN;
        END
    RETURN SELECT * FROM @TabResult
END
```

Comment: да это язык ms sql

Comment: Вопрос звучит как "есть ведро и колодец, опускаю ведро в колодец и вытаскиваю, но ведро то пустое, то в нем ничего нет"

Comment: Ну а если вызвать процедуру без Insert'a, то что-нибудь возвращается? Вроде, синтаксически все верно

Comment: Нужно убрать `RETURN` перед `SELECT * FROM @TabResult`. Вообще [RETURN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) может возвращать только одно целое значение и как правило используется для того, чтобы вернуть некий статус (успех/неуспех и тп). То есть сейчас происходит выход из процедуры до выполнения команды `SELECT * FROM @TabResult`.